# Ajax Complete Problem

Tags: jquery

I have a method which calls a another method which inturns has some ajax call to the back end.

```
MethodB(){
MethodA()// this has some ajax functionality 
setpopupposition()// wants to overwrite x,y postions after MethodA sets...X,y postion.
}

MetodhA(){
AjaxCall();
Setx Popup to x,y location
}
```

The problem here is MethodA sets the popup postion to a x,y location ,but i want to overwrite x,y location to a different postion after the call to MethodA.The issue i am facing here is my setpoupuppostion in MethodB is getting executed before MethodA.

I want to execute setupuppostion() inside MEthodB only after methodA completes, can you please advice me how to do that.

Comment: Could you show your actual code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MethodA is completing, though. All you have in Method A is the AJAX **call** and the popup position setting function. These will both get called and then Method B will move on. (Note Method A is not waiting for the AJAX call to complete. It's just initiating it.)

An alternative would be to have a callback generated by the AJAX call, true on success/false on failure, and then pass that on from Method A to Method B. In Method B you could implicitly wait for that return before continuing, or only continue if it's true.

```
function MethodB() {
    if (MethodA()) {
       setPopupPosition();
    }
}

function MethodA() {
    if (AjaxCall()) { // You need to edit your AjaxCall() to return true/false
        Setx Popup to x,y location
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

If you need help making your AJAX call return true/false, update the question with your existing AJAX method and I'll update it for you.

Comment: you should be doing Asynchronous here, not returning data from functions, this will causing blocking.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your trying to run synchronously which is not a good idea.

what you want to do is set a callback like so

```
function MethodA()
{
    AjaxCall(function(){
        //SET X / Y
    });
}

function AjaxCall(callback)
{
    $.post('blah',{data:x},function(){
        //now the data has returned

        callback(); //Executes the function defined in MethodA();

    });
}
```